# Find the product of negative and positive integers in one java method. Answer is printing 0

Tags: java, netbeans

I am learning about Java in university, I am very new to the topic. I am trying to get this method to print `The product of non-negatives = 21` and `The product of negatives = 10` But I am getting 0 for both instead of 21 and 10. I am only allowed to use one method to complete both calculations. Why is it equalling to 0? Thanks.

```
public class Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int num1 = -2, num2 = 3, num3 = 7, num4 = -5;

        findPosNegProd(num1, num2, num3, num4);
    }
public static void findPosNegProd(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4){



    int positives = 0;
    int negatives = 0;

    if(n1 > 0) positives *= n1;
    if(n2 > 0) positives *= n2;
    if(n2 > 0) positives *= n3;
    if(n3 > 0) positives *= n3;

    {
        if(n1 < 0) negatives *= n1;
    if(n2 < 0) negatives *= n2;
    if(n2 < 0) negatives *= n3;
    if(n3 < 0) negatives *= n3;
    }

    System.out.println("The product of non-negatives = " + positives);
    System.out.println("The product of negatives = " + negatives);
}
}
```

Comment: you have initialized to 0 and multiplying with it

Comment: Because you multiply with zero and then the result must be zero, Try to initialize with 1

Comment: just initialize your positives & negatives with 1 in place of 0

Comment: 0 times anything is 0.

Comment: You are repeating `if(n2 > 0)` and many such small mistakes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the variable `positives` and `negatives` with starting value of 1 and not `0` and also fix variables used.

```
public static void findPosNegProd(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4){

        int positives = 1;
        int negatives = 1;

        if(n1 > 0) positives *= n1;
        if(n2 > 0) positives *= n2;
        if(n3 > 0) positives *= n3;
        if(n4 > 0) positives *= n4;

        {
            if(n1 < 0) negatives *= n1;
            if(n2 < 0) negatives *= n2;
            if(n3 < 0) negatives *= n3;
            if(n4 < 0) negatives *= n4;
        }

        System.out.println("The product of non-negatives = " + positives);
        System.out.println("The product of negatives = " + negatives);
    }
```

Output:

> The product of non-negatives = 21 The product of negatives = 10

Answer (score 0):

```
int positives = 0;
int negatives = 0;
```

Both are initialized to 0.

Multiplying with this *will always give 0*.

set it to 1.

```
int positives = 1;
int negatives = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are multiplying by 0, so its always zero, you should add a validation to see if your `positives` or `negatives` are equal to 0

EDIT: if the numbers you will receive are fixed, then there is no problem to initialize the variables to 1... if you are to use this function else where, it may show the wrong result.

i.e: if all numbers are negative, your `positives` variable will show `1` when its really `0`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 0 because of this line

```
if(n1 > 0) positives *= n1;
```

The above line can be expanded as

```
if(n1 > 0)
{
   positives = positives * n1;
}
```

Since you have initilized positives & negaitives to 0, the result you receive is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
//I believe this code would solve your problem
public class NumberProduct
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int num1=-2, num2=3, num3=7, num4=-5;
       int negNo=1,posNo=1;

// This code is to sort the products by multiplying positive numbers and also negative numbers and storing them in different variables
if (num1<0)
{
 negNo=num1;
}
else
{
 posNo=num1;
}
if (num2<0)
{
 negNo*=num2;
}
else
{
 posNo*=num2;
}
if (num3<0)
{
 negNo*=num3;
}
else
{
 posNo*=num3;
}
if (num4<0)
{
 negNo*=num4;
}
else
{
 posNo*=num4;
}
  System.out.println("The product of negatives is " + negNo);
  System.out.println("The product of positives is " + posNo);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
It can also be solved by initializing your values into an array
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
//int num1=-2, num2=3, num3=7, num4=-5;
      int negatives=1, positives=1;
      int  num [] = { -2, 3, 7, -5};

      for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
         {
               if (num[i]<0)
               {
                  negatives*=num[i];
               }
               else
               {
                  positives*=num[i];
               }  
         }

         System.out.println("The product of negatives is " + negatives);
         System.out.println("The product of positives is " + positives);
      }
```